# tvML, can't get player to repeat, mediaItemWillChange doesn't fire?

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, tvos, tvml, tvjs

I'm new to tvML, so chances are I'm missing something easy... The script runs fine no errors, video plays, mediaItemWillChange event never fires to play the video again. Here's my tvJS code, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
App.onLaunch = function (options) {
var video = new MediaItem('video', 'https://localhost/file_example_MP4_1920_18MG.mp4');

var player = new Player();

var playlist = new Playlist();
player.playlist = playlist;
player.playlist.push(video);

var parser = new DOMParser();
var alertString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>'
    + '<document>'
    + '<alertTemplate>'
    + '</alertTemplate>'
    + '</document>';
var alertDoc = parser.parseFromString(alertString, "application/xml");  

player.interactiveOverlayDocument = alertDoc;
player.interactiveOverlayDismissable = false;

player.addEventListener("mediaItemWillChange", function (e) {
    player.playlist.push(video);
});

player.play();
}
```

Comment: how about set player.playlist.repeatMode = 1;

Comment: no such property in TVMLKit JS